# Anonymous users in Spring Security with JWT and Oauth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

Some background, we are building shopping cart where even those users who haven't logged in can add and delete to cart. This cart details are backed by Mongo data store. The resource server is using JWT token for verifying users.

The API has role based authz using `@Preauthorize` having valid permissions which receives the token from an API gateway. It doesn't help that we got unclear requirements saying pass GUID for guests from frontend(which is a React app).

Nothing mentioned so assuming a GUID/UUID is generated on the server which begs the question on why the anonymous user was passed through header and again having created of UUID on server.

I came across some answers using a extended Filter for anonymous users. Is there any standard way this can be handled with Spring Security and Oauth JWT? I am assuming since this is a stateless app the `session` is ruled out.

Update: This is a resource server which authenticates with the authentication server which is another microservice.
This is in the WebConfig of the project:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    /** The self token validator. */
    @Autowired
    SelfTokenValidator selfTokenValidator;

    /**
     * Adds the resource handlers.
     *
     * @param registry the registry
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    /**
     * Auth check filter.
     *
     * @return the filter
     */
    @Bean
    public Filter authCheckFilter() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationFilter(this.selfTokenValidator);

    }

    /**
     * Configure.
     *
     * @param http the http
     * @throws Exception the exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf()
                .disable().addFilterAfter(new RequestContextFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .formLogin().disable().httpBasic().disable().exceptionHandling().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/jwks.json", "/**/*.html", "/**/*.css", "/**/*.js", "/swagger-resources/**")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/auth/**", "/oauth/**").permitAll().anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.addFilterBefore(new TokenAuthenticationFilter(this.selfTokenValidator),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    /**
     * Xss prevent filter.
     *
     * @return the filter registration bean
     */
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<XSSFilter> xssPreventFilter() {
        final var registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<XSSFilter>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new XSSFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return registrationBean;
    }

}
```

**yaml**

```
auth:
  validation: SELF
  service-endpoints: http://env-host:port
```

**Filter class in the library added to project:**

```
@Component
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TokenAuthenticationFilter.class);
    @Autowired
    private final TokenValidator tokenValidator;

    public TokenAuthenticationFilter(final TokenValidator tokenValidator) {
        this.tokenValidator = tokenValidator;
    }

    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Authentication checkAuthentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (checkAuthentication == null || !checkAuthentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            String jwt = this.getJwtFromRequest(request);
            if (null != jwt) {
                try {
                    JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = this.tokenValidator.validateToken(jwt);
                    Map<String, Object> claims = claimsSet.getClaims();
                    if (claims.get("ual") != null) {
                        String userLoginId = (String)claims.get("sub");
                        Object claim = claims.get("ual");
                        String sgRole = String.valueOf(claim);
                        List<String> accessList = Arrays.asList(sgRole.split(","));
                        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList();
                        Iterator var13 = accessList.iterator();

                        while(var13.hasNext()) {
                            String authority = (String)var13.next();
                            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority));
                        }

                        JWTAuthenticationToken authentication = new JWTAuthenticationToken(userLoginId, grantedAuthorities);
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                    }
                } catch (Exception var15) {
                    log.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", var15);
                    response.setStatus(401);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        return StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ") ? bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length()) : null;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('P_SUP_R')")
    public ResponseEntity<ExampleDTO> getExamples(
            @Validated(ExampleViews.ExampleView.class) @RequestBody @JsonView(ExampleViews.ExampleView.class) final ExampleDTO Example,
            @RequestHeader(required = false, value = HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) final String token) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

**Edit 2:**
Authentication service

**CustomAuthenticationProvider**

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider, InitializingBean, MessageSourceAware {

    /** The Constant NONE_PROVIDED. */
    private static final String NONE_PROVIDED = "NONE_PROVIDED";

    /** The user service. */
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    /** The party login service. */
    @Autowired
    private PartyLoginService partyLoginService;

    /** The user request service. */
    @Autowired
    private UserRequestService userRequestService;

    /** The messages. */
    protected MessageSourceAccessor messages = SpringSecurityMessageSource.getAccessor();

    /** The force principal as string. */
    private boolean forcePrincipalAsString = false;

    /** The hide user not found exceptions. */
    protected boolean hideUserNotFoundExceptions = true;

    /** The pre authentication checks. */
    private DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks preAuthenticationChecks = new DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks();

    /** The post authentication checks. */
    private UserDetailsChecker postAuthenticationChecks = new DefaultPostAuthenticationChecks();

    /** The authorities mapper. */
    private GrantedAuthoritiesMapper authoritiesMapper = new NullAuthoritiesMapper();

    /** The user not found encoded password. */
    private volatile String userNotFoundEncodedPassword;

    /** The password encoder. */
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    /** The user details service. */
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    /** The Constant USER_NOT_FOUND_PASSWORD. */
    private static final String USER_NOT_FOUND_PASSWORD = "userNotFoundPassword";

    /** The Constant BAD_CREDENTIALS. */
    private static final String BAD_CREDENTIALS = "Bad credentials";

    /**
     * Creates the success authentication.
     *
     * @param principal      the principal
     * @param authentication the authentication
     * @param user           the user
     * @return the authentication
     */
    protected Authentication createSuccessAuthentication(Object principal, Authentication authentication,

            UserDetails user) {

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal,
                authentication.getCredentials(), authoritiesMapper.mapAuthorities(user.getAuthorities()));
        result.setDetails(authentication.getDetails());

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Authenticate User.
     *
     * @param authentication the authentication
     * @return the authentication
     * @throws AuthenticationException the authentication exception
     */
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        String username = (authentication.getPrincipal() == null) ? NONE_PROVIDED : authentication.getName();
        UserDetails user;
        try {
            var partyLogin = userService.findPartyLoginByLoginName(username)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with email : " + username));
            if (!partyLoginService.isPartyUserLoginEnabled(partyLogin)) {
                throw new DisabledException(USER_ACCOUNT_NOT_ENABLED);
            }
            user = UserPrincipal.create(partyLogin);
            user = partyLogin.getCredential().isMigrated().booleanValue()
                    ? processPasswordMigration(username, authentication, partyLogin.getCredential())
                    : user;
            preAuthenticationChecks.verifyUser(user, authentication instanceof UsernameOTPAuthenticationTokenDTO);
            additionalAuthenticationChecks(user, (AbstractAuthenticationToken) authentication);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException notFound) {
            log.error("User '" + username + "' not found", notFound);
            throw (hideUserNotFoundExceptions
                    ? new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(BAD_CREDENTIALS, INVALID_USERNAME))
                    : notFound);
        } catch (AuthenticationException exception) {
            log.error(ExceptionLogConstants.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, exception);
            throw exception;
        }
        postAuthenticationChecks.check(user);
        return createSuccessAuthentication(forcePrincipalAsString ? user.getUsername() : user, authentication, user);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve user.
     *
     * @param username       the username
     * @param authentication the authentication
     * @return the user details
     * @throws AuthenticationException the authentication exception
     */
    protected final UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, AbstractAuthenticationToken authentication) {
        prepareTimingAttackProtection();
        try {

            UserDetails loadedUser = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (loadedUser == null) {
                throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(
                        "UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation");
            }
            return loadedUser;
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException ex) {
            log.error(ExceptionLogConstants.RETRIEVE_USER_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, ex);
            mitigateAgainstTimingAttack(authentication);
            throw ex;
        } catch (InternalAuthenticationServiceException ex) {
            log.error(ExceptionLogConstants.RETRIEVE_USER_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, ex);
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ExceptionLogConstants.RETRIEVE_USER_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, ex);
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process password migration.
     *
     * @param username        the username
     * @param authentication  the authentication
     * @param partyCredential the party credential
     * @return the user details
     */
    private UserDetails processPasswordMigration(String username, Authentication authentication,
            PartyCredential partyCredential) {
        String dbpassword = partyCredential.getPassword();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        boolean passwordMatchingFlag = false;

        try {
            passwordMatchingFlag = HashCrypt.comparePassword(dbpassword, dbpassword, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(ExceptionLogConstants.PASSWORD_MIG_EXCEPTION_MSG, e);

            throw new BadRequestException(new ErrorInfo(ExceptionLogConstants.PASSWORD_MIG_EXCEPTION_MSG));
        }

        if (passwordMatchingFlag) {

            String encodedpassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
            userService.passwordMigration(username, encodedpassword);
            return retrieveUser(username, (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(BAD_CREDENTIALS, INVALID_PASSWORD_CREDENTIALS));

        }
    }

    /**
     * Additional authentication checks.
     *
     * @param userDetails    the user details
     * @param authentication the authentication
     * @throws AuthenticationException the authentication exception
     */
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, AbstractAuthenticationToken authentication) {
        if (authentication instanceof UsernameOTPAuthenticationTokenDTO) {
            authenticateUserForOtp(userDetails.getUsername(), authentication.getCredentials().toString());
        } else {
            authenticateUserForPassword(userDetails, authentication);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Authenticate user for password.
     *
     * @param userDetails    the user details
     * @param authentication the authentication
     */
    protected void authenticateUserForPassword(UserDetails userDetails, AbstractAuthenticationToken authentication) {
        if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
            log.debug("Authentication failed: no credentials provided");
            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(BAD_CREDENTIALS, INVALID_PASSWORD_CREDENTIALS));
        }

        String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (!passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, userDetails.getPassword())) {
            log.debug("Authentication failed: password does not match stored value");
            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(BAD_CREDENTIALS, INVALID_PASSWORD_CREDENTIALS));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Authenticate user for otp.
     *
     * @param username the username
     * @param otp      the otp
     */
    protected void authenticateUserForOtp(String username, String otp) {
        try {
            userRequestService.validateOtp(username, otp);
        } catch (UserRequestException userRequestException) {
            log.error(ExceptionLogConstants.OTP_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED);
            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(BAD_CREDENTIALS,
                    userRequestException.getErrors().getErrors().get(0).getErrorCode()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prepare timing attack protection.
     */
    private void prepareTimingAttackProtection() {
        if (this.userNotFoundEncodedPassword == null) {
            this.userNotFoundEncodedPassword = this.passwordEncoder.encode(USER_NOT_FOUND_PASSWORD);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Mitigate against timing attack.
     *
     * @param authentication the authentication
     */
    private void mitigateAgainstTimingAttack(AbstractAuthenticationToken authentication) {
        if (authentication.getCredentials() != null) {
            String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            this.passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, this.userNotFoundEncodedPassword);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the user details service.
     *
     * @return the user details service
     */
    public UserDetailsService getUserDetailsService() {
        return userDetailsService;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the user details service.
     *
     * @param userDetailsService the new user details service
     */
    public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    /**
     * Supports.
     *
     * @param authentication the authentication
     * @return true, if successful
     */
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the message source.
     *
     * @param messageSource the new message source
     */
    @Override
    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        log.info("setMessageSource");
    }

    /**
     * The Class DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks.
     */
    private class DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks implements UserDetailsChecker {

        /** The is otp login requested. */
        private boolean isOtpLoginRequested = false;

        /**
         * Verify user.
         *
         * @param userDetails         the user details
         * @param isOtpLoginRequested the is otp login requested
         */
        public void verifyUser(UserDetails userDetails, boolean isOtpLoginRequested) {
            this.isOtpLoginRequested = isOtpLoginRequested;
            check(userDetails);
        }

        /**
         * Check User Activity.
         *
         * @param user the user
         */
        @Override
        public void check(UserDetails user) {
            if (!isOtpLoginRequested && !user.isAccountNonLocked()) {
                log.debug("User account is locked");

                throw new LockedException(messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.locked",
                        "User account is locked"));
            }

            if (!user.isEnabled()) {
                log.debug("User account is disabled");

                throw new DisabledException(
                        messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.disabled", "User is disabled"));
            }

            if (!user.isAccountNonExpired()) {
                log.debug("User account is expired");

                throw new AccountExpiredException(messages
                        .getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.expired", "User account has expired"));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The Class DefaultPostAuthenticationChecks.
     */
    private class DefaultPostAuthenticationChecks implements UserDetailsChecker {

        /**
         * Check User Credentials Expiry.
         *
         * @param user the user
         */
        @Override
        public void check(UserDetails user) {
            if (!user.isCredentialsNonExpired()) {
                log.debug("User account credentials have expired");

                throw new CredentialsExpiredException(
                        messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.credentialsExpired",
                                "User credentials have expired"));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * After properties set.
     *
     * @throws Exception the exception
     */
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        log.info("inside  afterPropertiesSet");
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
private AuthenticationResponseDTO buildAuthenticationResponse(final HttpServletRequest request,
            boolean generateRefreshToken, final String[] grantTypes, final boolean isCustomerSite,
            final HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication authentication;
        if (Constants.GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD.equalsIgnoreCase(grantTypes[0])
                || Constants.GRANT_TYPE_OTP.equalsIgnoreCase(grantTypes[0])) {
            authentication = buildAuthenticationToken(grantTypes[0], request);
            authentication = this.customAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
            if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserPrincipal) {
                UserPrincipal user = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
                this.userService.logSignInActivity(user.getPartyLogin(), AuthProvider.LOCAL.toString());
            }
            generateRefreshToken = true;
        } else if (Constants.GRANT_TYPE_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS.equalsIgnoreCase(grantTypes[0])) {
            authentication = this.authenticationConverter.convert(request);
            authentication = this.clientAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
        } else if (Constants.GRANT_TYPE_REFRESH_TOKEN.equalsIgnoreCase(grantTypes[0])) {
            authentication = authenticateRefreshTokenRequest(request);
        } else {
            throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(new OAuth2Error(OAuth2ErrorCodes.UNSUPPORTED_GRANT_TYPE));
        }
        return this.authTokenService.createToken(authentication, generateRefreshToken, isCustomerSite, response);
    }
```

**token service**

```
public AuthenticationResponseDTO createToken(final Authentication authentication, final boolean withRefreshToken,
            boolean isCustomerSite, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserPrincipal) {
            final var userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
            return createToken(userPrincipal, null, withRefreshToken, isCustomerSite, response);
        } else {
            final var client = (Client) authentication.getPrincipal();
            return createToken(null, client, withRefreshToken, isCustomerSite, response);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is to create the token.
     *
     * @param userPrincipal    the user principal
     * @param client           the client
     * @param withRefreshToken the with refresh token
     * @return the authentication response
     */
    public AuthenticationResponseDTO createToken(final UserPrincipal userPrincipal, final Client client,
            final boolean withRefreshToken, boolean isCustomerSite, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        long tokenExpirationTime = isCustomerSite ? this.appProperties.getAuth().getAccessTokenExpirationMsecBC()
                : this.appProperties.getAuth().getAccessTokenExpirationMsecBB();
        final var expTime = Date.from(Instant.now().plusMillis(tokenExpirationTime));
        final var uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        String uid = null;
        String name = null;
        String userType = null;
        if (userPrincipal != null) {
            uid = userPrincipal.getPartyLogin().getId();
            name = userPrincipal.getName();
            userType = userPrincipal.getPrincipalType();
        } else {
            uid = client.getClientId();
            name = client.getClientId();
            userType = "CLIENT";
        }

        final var token = generateAccessToken(uid, name, userType, expTime, uuid, userPrincipal);
        String refreshToken = null;
        if (withRefreshToken) {
            log.debug("Generating the refresh token ....");
            refreshToken = generateRefreshToken(uid, userType, isCustomerSite);
        }

        response.addHeader(Constants.HEADER_SAME_SITE, Constants.HEADER_SAME_SITE_VALUE);
        response.addHeader(Constants.HEADER_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS, Constants.HEADER_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS_VALUE);
        CookieUtils.addCookie(response, Constants.TOKEN, token, 0);

        return new AuthenticationResponseDTO(token, Constants.AUTH_TYPE_BEARER, expTime.getTime(), uuid, refreshToken);
    }

    /**
     * This method is to generate access token.
     *
     * @param principalId   the principal id
     * @param principalName the principal name
     * @param principalType the principal type
     * @param authorities   the authorities
     * @param expTime       the exp time
     * @param uuid          the uuid
     * @return the string
     */
    private String generateAccessToken(final String principalId, final String principalName, final String principalType,
            final Date expTime, final String uuid, final UserPrincipal userPrincipal) {
        String partyId = null;
        String partyName = null;
        if (userPrincipal != null) {
            partyId = userPrincipal.getPartyLogin().getPartyId();
            partyName = userPrincipal.getPartyLogin().getPartyName();
        }

        final var header = new JWSHeader.Builder(JWSAlgorithm.RS256).keyID(this.rsaJWK.getKeyID()).build();
        final var issTimeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final var issTime = new Date(issTimeInMillis);

        final var accessToken = storeAccessToken(principalId, principalType, uuid, issTime);

        final var builder = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder();
        builder.expirationTime(expTime).subject(principalId).issuer(this.appProperties.getAuth().getTokenIssuer())
                .audience(this.appProperties.getAuth().getTokenIssuer()).notBeforeTime(issTime).jwtID(uuid)
                .claim("ati", accessToken.getId()).claim("ciat", (issTimeInMillis / 1000)).claim("uname", principalName)
                .claim("pid", partyId).claim("partyName", partyName);

        final var claims = builder.build();
        final var signedJWT = new SignedJWT(header, claims);
        try {
            signedJWT.sign(this.signer);
        } catch (final JOSEException e) {
            log.error(ExceptionLogConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXCEPTION_MSG, e);
            throw new BadRequestException(new ErrorInfo(ExceptionLogConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXCEPTION_MSG));
        }

        return signedJWT.serialize();
    }
```

config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    /** The otp authentication provider. */
    @Autowired
    private UsernameOTPAuthenticationProvider otpAuthenticationProvider;

    /** The o auth 2 authentication success handler. */
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    /** The o auth 2 authentication failure handler. */
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

    /** The custom authentication provider. */
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    /** The token validator. */
    @Autowired
    private TokenValidator tokenValidator;

    /** The user permission provider. */
    @Autowired
    private UserPermissionProvider userPermissionProvider;

    /** The cookie authorization request repository. */
    @Autowired
    private HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository;

    /**
     * Auth check filter.
     *
     * @return the filter
     */
    @Bean
    public Filter authCheckFilter() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationFilter(this.tokenValidator, this.userPermissionProvider);
    }

    /**
     * Authentication manager bean.
     *
     * @return the authentication manager
     * @throws Exception the exception
     */
    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    /**
     * Configure.
     *
     * @param authenticationManagerBuilder the authentication manager builder
     * @throws Exception the exception
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(this.otpAuthenticationProvider);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(this.customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    /**
     * Configure.
     *
     * @param http the http
     * @throws Exception the exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf()
                .disable().addFilterAfter(new RequestContextFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .formLogin().disable().httpBasic().disable().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint()).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/jwks.json", "/**/*.html", "/**/*.css", "/**/*.js", "/swagger-resources/**")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/auth/**", "/oauth/**").permitAll().anyRequest().permitAll().and()
                .oauth2Login().authorizationEndpoint().baseUri("/oauth/authorize")
                .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository).and().redirectionEndpoint()
                .baseUri("/oauth/callback/*").and().userInfoEndpoint().userService(this.customOAuth2UserService()).and()
                .successHandler(this.oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(this.oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);
        http.addFilterBefore(new RequestContextFilter(), OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterBefore(new TokenAuthenticationFilter(this.tokenValidator, this.userPermissionProvider),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    /**
     * Custom O auth 2 user service.
     *
     * @return the custom O auth 2 user service
     */
    @Bean
    public CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService() {
        return new CustomOAuth2UserService();
    }

    /**
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't provided any technical details, so it's quite difficult to answer your question (or indeed understand what you're really asking). For example, you mention a resource server, but not who owns it. What does **your** application look like, what role in this architecture does your app play, what details of the architecture are you in control of vs which details have been dictated to you (and what are they), what does a request look like? I'd like to help, as these types of architecture questions can be interesting, but there are a number of details missing.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Added some context about the security applied to this microservice which is a resource server

Comment: You aren't using Spring Security for authentication, and instead are using a custom filter (which appears to be decompiled source). While there are many tutorials online that do this, Spring Security has had built-in support for JWT authentication for a few years now, using the `.oauth2ResoureServer()` DSL. Please read the chapter of the docs on [OAuth2 Resource Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html). As far as authorization, try `isAnonymous()` in your `@PreAuthorize`.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Added some more code from the auth service. The decompiled code comes from a library called common-auth. The token is generated from the endpoint /oauth/token from the auth service. The `@config` here doesn't have any annotation marking `@EnableAuthorisationServer` anywhere. Spring boot version is 2.4.6. Just wanted to add more context.